# WPF Adding tab items to tab control from multiple view models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

On my MainWindow I have a `TabControl` whose `ItemSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<TabItem>` In it's View Model (vmMainWindow).

On the Main Window I also have a `Menu` with 2 `MenuItems`, (Albums, Artists)

I have created a `Page` and `ViewModel` for both Albums and Artists.

When a `MenuItem` is clicked, using a `RelayCommand` I am creating a `Frame` to hold the relevent `Page` bound to it's respective View Model. Then i create a new `TabItem` set it's `Content` to the new `Frame` then add the new `TabItem` to the `ObservableCollection<TabItem>`.

```
    void MenuItemClick(object parameter)
    {
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "Albums":
                Frame albumsFrame = new Frame { Content = new pgAlbums { DataContext = new vmAlbums() } };
                TabCollection.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Albums", Content = albumsFrame , IsSelected = true });
                break;
            case "Artists":
                Frame artistsFrame = new Frame { Content = new pgArtists { DataContext = new vmArtists() } };
                TabCollection.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Artists", Content = artistsFrame , IsSelected = true });
                break;
        }
    }
```

What i would like to do is to be able to add tabs to the `ObservableCollection<TabItem>` the same way from the other `Page`'s View Models but I don't have access to the TabCollection from them. I either need somewhere global to place it instead or somehow share it between View Models.

I am aware I am going about this all the wrong way so i'm putting it out here so someone can guide me in the right direction about what to do. I'm a complete newbie to MVVM, i have only experience in Winforms, but want to move on from that.

Comment: Are you using Prism? You could use the EventAggregator to fire an event that the vmMainWindow subscribes to and add it in the handler. If not then an event based system that again the vmMainWindow listens to events from the tabItems VM’s

Comment: No just created a C# WPF application in Visual Studio, you mean I could create a void in the vmMainWindow that adds the tabs to the tabcollection when i need them to from the other VM's through an Event? Hadn't thought of that thank you! How do i go about getting the vmMainWindow to listen to Events from other VM's?

Comment: OK got it! Think i can go from here and keep learning, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `EventAggregator` or a `Messenger` class to send a message that the other view model subscribes to. Please refer to the following links for more information about the concept.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger

https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

The other options would be to either inject both view models with a shared service or keep a strong reference to the first view model from the second one and raise an event.

The benefit of using an event aggregator or a messenger is that you avoid introducing a tight coupling between publisher of the event and the subscriber which should make the application easier to maintain. Both the publisher and the subscriber of the event or message knows only about the event aggregator or messenger but they don't know anything about each other.

By the way, you shouldn't create `TabItems` or any other visual elements in a view model. You should create instances of data objects that may be represented by visual elements such as `TabItems` in the view.

Comment: Thank you for this answer I appreciate it. I will go and have a good read of the links provided. I have read many times it's not right to be creating visual elements in the view model but as of yet I just can't wrap my head around how to do it the proper way. I am hoping in time it will come to me if i keep reading and finding examples.